# Is there a signature-taking attendance app for iOS?

Tags: ios, applications, software-recommendation

I have a hobby organization that records sign-ins on a weekly basis. I would like to find an app that allows me to take attendance and have each attendee sign that they were present, then be able to generate a printable sign-in sheet that can go in the printed records.

Does anyone know of such an app? I've found good attendance apps, and I've found apps to take signatures though they usually only allow for one person to sign. I need the best of both worlds!

Answer (score 1):

I've used [FormEntry](http://www.widgetpress.com/formentry) for Mac to do this at team meetings. I push out the form to an iPad, and send the completed signed roster to a PDF when the meeting is completed. Caveat: you do need the Mac to design the form, and then you need to push the form to the iPad when completed. This might not be the most cost effective solution, but it works nicely for this and other applications.